# Change Kendo UI Upload culture

Tags: file-upload, kendo-ui, culture

I would like to change the text of the Kendo UI Upload button "Select files.." for es-ES culture.

I was reviewing the kendo.culture.es-ES.min.js file but I don´t see any parameter to change.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every widget has its own localization settings which allow you to change the messages. For the upload control they are all listed [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/upload#configuration-localization).

Comment: Petur I´m rendering a lot of "kendo ui upload widget" dynamically and I try to used the code:  $(".k-button.k-upload-button input").each(function (i, e) {        
        $("#" + e.id).kendoUpload({
            localization: {
                select: "customSelect"
            }
        });
    }); but it is not working fine